# I'm not able to get the name attribute of a button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having many buttons with the same id but different name.But I'm unable to get the name attribute value in `jquery` for a clicked button.I searched in StackOverflow and got many suggestions about my issue.But still, I'm unable to fix my problem. Anyone, please help.

I'm giving only my `jquery` code here:

```js
<script>
$(document).click('#grant',function(){
 $name=$(this).attr("name");
 alert($name);
});
</script>
```

Here grant is the id given for the buttons. I want to fetch only the name attr of clicked button. I tried with `this` operator. But alert box shows `undefined`.
Need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: *I'm having many buttons with same id* <- You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: @Eddie But its working fine.. I just given a dummy value in alert box and when I clicks on each button, it shows that dummy value

Comment: @JR.MaRtin **No**! It's absolutely not okay to write HTML codes with errors in syntax. Working fine it's because your browser rectifies some of the problems; there is no guarantee all browsers can help resolve your issues completely. Fix the syntax and logic error before moving on.

Comment: ok.....................

Comment: Like others told you should not use same id for multiple elements. But why your code is not working? you have to add the click event to the button using `on` instead of `click`. like `$(document).on('click', '#grant',function(){` then it will give you the name of the clicked button's name. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yhndxa9e/13/

Answer (score 0):

You confused about the use of `this`.

The codes you should use is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $('#grant' + i).click(function() {
         alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
}
```

The `this` here refers to the `#grant0` to `#grant99` element.

Besides, in 1 HTML document, ID should be unique, and can only be used once. Please assign a different ID to every different element.

Comment: oho.. I'm fetching values from database, and I used while loop to print each button. So how will I get name attr of each buttons

Comment: Please update your question by showing the structure you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same id for all elements, use class for such situations. id use used to uniquely identify an element as the name says. Having multiple elements with same id is not a good practice.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="button1" class="btn">Button1</button>
<button name="button2" class="btn">Button2</button>
<button name="button3" class="btn">Button3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id. You have to use class.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".grant").click(function(){
  $name=$(this).attr("name");
  console.log($name);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="grant anotherclass" name="1">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" class="grant anotherclass" name="2">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" class="grant anotherclass" name="3">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" class="grant anotherclass" name="4">Click Me!</button>
```

If your buttons are dynamically added, you can use `on`

```
$("body").on('click', '.grant', function( event ) {
    $name=$(this).attr("name");
    alert($name);
});
```

Comment: But already I uses class for bootstrap.Is it possible to give multiple classes for a button

Comment: Yes, You can separate by a space. Please see updated code. @JR.MaRtin

Comment: Can you post your updated code? You can use jsfiddle.com

Comment: @JR.MaRtin I am using `console.log` and not `alert` on my example. You might need to check the developer's tools. I added another example for dynamically added buttons.

Comment: This is php code to make button..I donno How to make it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Did you check the developer tools? I am using `console.log` on the example. You will not see an `alert`. @JR.MaRtin

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Comment: Please accept my answer if this helped you. @JR.MaRtin